how to scale quartz scheduler & executor separately?
i have a service that listens to a message queue and schedule jobs based on the message received.
I'm planning to use spring & quartz.
Is it possible to scale the message receiver and job executor independently?
Thus, I'm thinking, this means I have to scale the job scheduler and job executor independently. How do I achieve this? I am confused on how to separate the scheduler and executor on different instances using Quartz. They look very tightly coupled.
Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
JobDetail job = ...
Trigger trigger = newTrigger...
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
// and the job will run on the specified time!

Does it mean job scheduler need to be in stopped state (so that it wont execute jobs but still can schedule jobs) and scheduler in the job executor instance is in running state?
Thanks


Separate Scheduler and Executor Roles

Scheduler Node:

This node will only be responsible for receiving messages and scheduling jobs.
It will not execute any jobs but will use the Quartz scheduler to schedule jobs.

Executor Node:

This node will only be responsible for executing the jobs scheduled by the Scheduler Node.
It will be configured to pick up and execute the jobs from the Quartz job store.


Configure Quartz with a Persistent Job Store

To achieve this separation, you must configure Quartz to use a persistent job store, such as a relational database, that both Scheduler and Executor nodes can access. This allows the Scheduler node to schedule jobs that the Executor node will pick up and execute.
Application.properties:
# Common Quartz configuration
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDataSource
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=MyScheduler

Scheduler Node Configuration:
# Scheduler node specific configuration
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=0  # No threads for job execution

Executor Node Configuration:
# Executor node specific configuration
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=10  # Adjust according to your needs


Set Up Quartz Scheduler

Scheduler Node (Spring Configuration):
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Scheduler scheduler() throws SchedulerException {
        SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        return scheduler;
    }

    // Method to schedule jobs
    public void scheduleJob(Scheduler scheduler, JobDetail jobDetail, Trigger trigger) throws SchedulerException {
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    }
}

Executor Node (Spring Configuration):
@Configuration
public class ExecutorConfig {

    @Bean
    public Scheduler scheduler() throws SchedulerException {
        SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        return scheduler;
    }
}


Deploying Scheduler and Executor Nodes

Deploy the Scheduler Node: This instance will run the code to receive messages and schedule jobs using the SchedulerConfig class. Deploy the Executor Node: This instance will only run the Quartz scheduler and execute jobs from the database.

Handling Job Execution Logic

In your job class, ensure that it contains the logic to execute the job correctly. Here’s an example:
public class MyJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        // Job execution logic
        System.out.println("Job is executing...");
    }
}


Scheduling Jobs in the Scheduler Node

Whenever a message is received, you can schedule a job like this:
@Autowired
private Scheduler scheduler;

public void scheduleNewJob(String jobName, String jobGroup, Class<? extends Job> jobClass, Date startTime) throws SchedulerException {
    JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(jobClass)
                                    .withIdentity(jobName, jobGroup)
                                    .build();

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                                    .withIdentity(jobName, jobGroup)
                                    .startAt(startTime)
                                    .build();

    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
}

This is only an example of how it could be done.
Spring doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/io/quartz.html

thx for ur answer, but i got error on scheduler node
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Thread count must be > 0

Switch to number of threads to 1

I tried with 1 thread count, the node will also execute the jobs. thus no separation is achieved :(

Quartz provides a dedicated ZeroSizeThreadPool for the node which is not intended for running jobs. Its JavaDoc also mentions that the scheduler on that node should not be start()ed at all.
